# Dynamic Time Warping for geology time series, Matlab

Tags: matlab

Background: 
          Basically I'm using a dynamic time warping algorithm like used in speech recognition to try to  warp geological data (filter out noise from environmental conditions) The main difference between these two problems is that dtw prints a warping function that allows both vectors that are input to be warped, whereas for the problem I'm trying to solve I need to keep one reference vector constant while stretching and shrinking the test variable vector to fit.

here is dtw in matlab:

```
function [Dist,D,k,w]=dtw()
%Dynamic Time Warping Algorithm
%Dist is unnormalized distance between t and r
%D is the accumulated distance matrix
%k is the normalizing factor
%w is the optimal path
%t is the vector you are testing against
%r is the vector you are testing
[t,r,x1,x2]=randomtestdata();
[rows,N]=size(t);
[rows,M]=size(r);
%for n=1:N
%    for m=1:M
%        d(n,m)=(t(n)-r(m))^2;
%    end
%end
d=(repmat(t(:),1,M)-repmat(r(:)',N,1)).^2; %this replaces the nested for loops from         above Thanks Georg Schmitz 

D=zeros(size(d));
D(1,1)=d(1,1);

for n=2:N
    D(n,1)=d(n,1)+D(n-1,1);
end
for m=2:M
    D(1,m)=d(1,m)+D(1,m-1);
end
for n=2:N
    for m=2:M
        D(n,m)=d(n,m)+min([D(n-1,m),D(n-1,m-1),D(n,m-1)]);
    end
end

Dist=D(N,M);
n=N;
m=M;
k=1;
w=[];
w(1,:)=[N,M];
while ((n+m)~=2)
    if (n-1)==0
        m=m-1;
    elseif (m-1)==0
        n=n-1;
    else 
      [values,number]=min([D(n-1,m),D(n,m-1),D(n-1,m-1)]);
      switch number
      case 1
        n=n-1;
      case 2
        m=m-1;
      case 3
        n=n-1;
        m=m-1;
      end
  end
    k=k+1;
    w=cat(1,w,[n,m]);
end
w=flipud(w)

%w is a matrix that looks like this:

%    1 1
%    1 2
%    2 2
%    3 3
%    3 4
%    3 5
%    4 5
%    5 6
%    6 6
```

so what this is saying is that the both the first and second points of the second vector should be mapped to the first point of the first vector. i.e. 1 1
                                                              1 2
and that the fifth and sixth points on the first vector should be mapped to the second vector at point six. etc. so w contains the x coordinates of the warped data.

Normally I would be able to say

```
X1=w(:,1);
X2=w(:,2);
for i=1:numel(reference vector)
 Y1(i)=reference vector(X1(i));
 Y2(i)=test vector(X2(i));
end
```

but I need not to stretch the reference vector so I need to use the repeats in X1 to know how to shrink Y2 and the repeats in X2 to know how to stretch Y2 rather than using repeats in X1 to stretch Y1 and repeats in X2 to stretch Y2.

I tried using a find method to find the repeats in both X1 and X2 and then average(shrink) or interpolate linearly(stretch) as needed but the code became very complicated and difficult to debug.

Was this really unclear? I had a hard time explaining this problem, but I just need to know how to take w and create a Y2 that is stretched and shrunk accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure whether this extensive explanation is relevant. Assuming this is your only question you could perhaps just show one or two examples of W and Y2 as they are now and as what the Y2 should turn into.

Comment: Can you show some plots of what you have and of what you want?

Comment: "Was this really unclear?"  You probably felt so yourself if you asked.  I certainly have a hard time following what you are after in the end.  Background explanation is fine but you need to state your question succinctly, ideally in a way where that background info is almost superfluous.

Comment: Note: I answered a question on time warping here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283816/image-with-accordion-effect but I don't think this is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, here's DTW in Matlab translated from the pseudocode on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping):

```
t = 0:.1:2*pi;
x0 = sin(t) + rand(size(t)) * .1;
x1 = sin(.9*t) + rand(size(t)) * .1;

figure
plot(t, x0, t, x1);
hold on

DTW = zeros(length(x0), length(x1));
DTW(1,:) = inf;
DTW(:,1) = inf;
DTW(1,1) = 0;

for i0 = 2:length(x0)
    for i1 = 2:length(x1)
        cost = abs(x0(i0) - x1(i1));
        DTW(i0, i1) = cost + min( [DTW(i0-1, i1) DTW(i0, i1-1) DTW(i0-1, i1-1)] );
    end
end
```

Whether you are warping `x_0` onto `x_1`, `x_1` onto `x_0`, or warping them onto each other, you can get your answer out of the matrix `DTW`. In your case:

```
[cost, path] = min(DTW, [], 2);
plot(t, x1(path));
legend({'x_0', 'x_1', 'x_1 warped to x_0'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but I have been playing with the code of @tokkot implemented from the pseudocode in the Wikipedia article. It works, but I think it lacks three requeriments of DTW:

1. The first and last points of both sequences must be a match, with the use of min(), some (or many) of the first and ending points of one of the sequences are lost.
2. The output sequence is not monotonically increasing. I have used x1(sort(path)) instead, but I don't believe it is the real minimum distance.
3. Additionally, for a reason I haven't found yet, some intermediate points of the warped sequences are lost, which I believe is not compatible with DTW.

I'm still searching for an algorithm like DTW in which one of the sequences is fixed (not warped). I need to compare a time series of equally spaced temperature measurements with another sequence. The first one cannot be time shifted, it does not make sense.